# InvalidOperationException at userManager.FindByNameAsync

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am doing:

```
var response = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
```

This happens in an iteration. When FindByNameAsync is called the first time, the execution does not wait for the result, but instead the next iteration in the outer loop is started.  And then at the second execution I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext

Why is this happening?

Comment: There is not enough info here. Where and how this is invoked? How DbContext is registered? Can you please post a [mre]?

Comment: Yes, not enough info here. Try DbContext Pooling if you have multiple calls parallely to your database, or check if another process is running and you have called a second operation before thats completed. Finally, use CancellationToken where ever possible.

Comment: Please paste the code where this is called in iteration.

Comment: there's another call to the database in the same context simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

In the outer loop, I was using:

`reports.forEach(async report =>`

I changed it to

`foreach (Report report in reports)`

and now it works